# Are questions about the intended audience of a biblical text on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I have a few questions in mind to ask along these lines but am waiting to see what happens with [this question](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/12762/which-of-pauls-letters-were-written-to-strangers). (I voted to keep open.) This doesn’t seem to clearly fall into any of the categories listed [here](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (except possibly “historical context”?) , but we do have a tag called “authorial intent” which would fit nicely with these sorts of questions. It seems to me that they should be on topic (although I’m biased – I want to ask them!), but I’d like clarify.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, I think these questions should be on-topic and perhaps tagged as either [audience](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/audience) or [destination](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/destination).

We've generally allowed these kind of introductory matters such as [provenance](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/provenance), [authorship](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/authorship), [dating](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dating), or even [canonicity](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/canonicity). I don't see why audience would be would be any different from those. The intended audience is a key part of the interpretive process for certain hermeneutics. Our FAQ does seem to exclude a number of items which are, in fact, considered on-topic here. For instance, another glaring omission from that list is [textual-criticism](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/textual-criticism), which is one of our most popular tags.

In this particular question's case, it would maybe have been better to ask about a particular letter. Expanding it to thirteen letters makes any single answer difficult to defend for having to cover so much turf. But on the whole, I don't think it is off topic.

Comment: I hadn't seen the "audience" tag - good point!

Comment: @Susan Oh, I don't think there is one yet. But we should create it. Which if we do, hopefully someone has a second question to ask for the tag

Comment: [This question](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/12816/what-evidence-exists-to-show-that-the-galatians-could-understand-greek) posted yesterday could also take the "audience" tag. Can we create it? I'm not familiar with the process for that.

Comment: @Susan I was waiting until there was a consensus before creating the tag, but seems like we have enough to proceed (which I have done). As long as you have enough reputation (150), you can create a tag just by typing it in when you're adding or editing tags on a question and it will be automatically created. [Creating a tag wiki](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tags/audience/info) for it is a good idea too, though not necessary.

Comment: Thanks! It seems like your meta post has been highly upvoted, but it would be nice also in this regard to be sure Jas3.1's question is going to stay open, since it seems like topicality was the issue there. Is there a way to tell whether it's still pending vs voted-to-keep-open?

Comment: @Susan it's open, not 'pending' or 'on hold' or anything like that. It's got 2 close votes hanging off it but those will age away unless it is joined by another 3 (which I think is fairly unlikely).